# Discord.py get all name and discrims for members in guild (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord

class Bot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(ctx, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ctx.loop.create_task(ctx.get_all_members())

    async def get_all_members(ctx):
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
             print(member)

bot = Bot()
bot.run("My Token Here", bot=False)
```

**
Error

line 10, in get_all_members
for member in ctx.guild.members:
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'guild'

Comment: Can you try my code without doing the get_all_members()?
and try removing the await asyncio.sleep(10)

Comment: @Ahmed Khaled when i use your code i get error

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command in discord to run it `$get_names`.

Keep in your mind if you have a lot of members in the guild it will make an error it can’t send a large message. But you can save it as txt or just `print` it

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print("------")



@bot.command()
async def get_names(ctx):
  names = list()
  for user in ctx.guild.members:
    names.append(user.name)
    
  await ctx.channel.send('\n'.join(names))

bot.run(TOKEN_HERE)
```